Unable to get "id" even though it is working perfectly in other functions and everything is right
So I wrote this function which calls a function in a different file use Context in React JS
I am getting this error only in this function as in other function which are similar it works perfectly
Code
Index.js
import { useContext } from "react";
import { PlaygroundContext } from "../../../Providers/PlaygroundProvider";
import { ModalContext, modalConstants } from "../../../Providers/ModalProvider";
import { Modal } from "../../../Providers/Modals/Modal.js";

const Folder = ({folderTitle, cards, id, file}) =>{

    const {deleteFolder, deleteFile} =useContext(PlaygroundContext);
    const {openModal} = useContext(ModalContext)
    const {folders} = useContext(PlaygroundContext)
    const navigate = useNavigate();

 
    const onDeleteFile = () => {
        deleteFile(id, file.id);
    }

     return(  
                        <div><span class="material-symbols-outlined" onClick={onDeleteFile}>delete</span>
                        {/* <span class="material-symbols-outlined">edit</span> */}
                        </div>


)             

This is the function
    const deletefile = (fileId, id) => {
        console.log(id, fileId);
        const copiedFolders = [...folders]
        for(let i=0 ; i < copiedFolders.length; i++){
            if(copiedFolders[i].id === id){
                const files = [...copiedFolders[i].files];
                copiedFolders[i].files = files.filter((file) => {
                    return file.id !== fileId;
                })
                break;
            }
        }
        localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(copiedFolders));
        setFolders(copiedFolders);
    }


Later I pass it to the index file properly
And the error is
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at onDeleteFile (http://localhost:3000/main.a4ed982a4138ab8e8eb8.hot-update.js:72:25)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:34521:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:34565:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:34622:35)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:34636:29)
    at executeDispatch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38779:7)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38805:11)
    at processDispatchQueue (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38816:9)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38825:7)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38985:16

I tried debugging using various method but they didnt work at all...

Well, the error message tells you that file is undefined, so this is what you should figure out.  You're not giving any information about where file is coming from, so we can't really help you.

did you try logging file before executing?
const onDeleteFile = () => {
   console.log({file, id: file.id})
   // deleteFile(id, file.id)
}

